# Accessing Modal with form (child component) from Parent component in React `class component `

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I have a `Modal` with a `Form` (child component) called from a parent component in `React`/`TypeScript` class component using `Antd V4` library for styling purpose as below.

**Parent Component**

```js
class parent extends React.component<IProps,IState> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            visible: false,
        }
    }

    handleCreate = () => {
        // Should I have to call form submission here in parent using props?
    }

    handleCancel = () => {
        this.setState({ visible: false });
    }
    
    render() {
        return(
            <ChildModal visible={this.state.visible} onCancel={this.handleCancel}
        onCreate={this.handleCreate} ref={this.formRef}/>
        );
    }
}
```

**Child Modal with Form Component**

```js
class ChildModal extends React.Component<IProps,IState> {

    // Should i have to call form submit here and then pass values to parent using props?**

    render() {
        const { visible, onCancel, onCreate, formRef } = this.props;
        return (
            <Modal visible={visible} onOk={onCreate} onCancel={onCancel}>
                <Form></Form>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}
```

As I am new to `React` and `Antd V4`, please help with procedure to be followed and and also where to handle `onCreate` function, parent or child?

Comment: Ideally, you'd want to handle the `onCreate` as close to the form as possible (meaning handling it in `ChildModal` in this case). But it really depends on what the `onCreate` function will be doing.

Comment: @juliomalves `onCreate` function to submit form values.